# Valid ObservableCollection cast throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am receiving an InvalidCastException for setting two types equal to each other.  Thoughts on the particular behavior that might cause this?

- Defining this.governanceTemplateList with the field definition does not change the exception.
- Defining this.governanceTemplateList as a new ObservableCollection in the constructor throws the exact same exception.
- The following code is in a WCF service library, using .NET 4.0.

[Screenshots of Editor, Exception, Watch, and References.](http://imgur.com/kxfqu,DJ9zb#1)

**SOLUTION:**

Daniel Hilgarth is correct, it was the line of code above that was throwing the exception.  I was casting a null value as a nullable value (DateTime?), but implicit casts cannot convert null values.  In order to cast properly, you must use the AS keyword.

```
governanceTemplateTimestamp = (DateTime?)dr["GovernanceTemplateTimestamp"]; //Invalid

governanceTemplateTimestamp = dr["GovernanceTemplateTimestamp"] as DateTime?; //Valid
```

Comment: Show some code.  If you are getting an invalid cast exception at runtime, what is in your object canot be cast to what you are casting it to e.g. the following would cause it

`object o = "word";`
`int i = (int)o;`

Comment: All of the relevant code is shown in the link with screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is most likely happening at the line above. The line that is marked as the offending one isn't executing any cast.
I guess that `GovernanceTemplateTimestamp` is `DBNull` in your DataRow. `DBNull` can't be cast to `DateTime?`.